# Using the Symfony Router with vue.js

Tags: symfony, vue.js, routes

I'm quite new to symfony and a litte bit experienced in vue.js. After a bit of research I wasn't able to find a solution to my problem.

I have the following problem:

I'm building a multi-page-application with Symfony and vue.js for the frontend. I use a search-form in my template `index.html.twig` to get information about the given search query from an API.

Therefore I use routing with Symfony. When hitting the search button the URL `xxx/search?query=test` is called. This URL is handled by my symfony controller which gets data from the API and renders the page `search-result.html.twig`. I use Vue.js in `index.html.twig` and I want to use Vue in `search-result.html.twig` (and other routes and pages) as well, but I'm not quite sure how to use different vue instances on different pages.

I hope I was able to describe the problem properly! Looking forward to your suggestions.

**UPDATE:**

This is my current infrastructure:

base.html.twig (all other pages inherit from this template):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
   </body>
   {% block javascripts %}
     {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
   {% endblock %}
</html>
```

This is how I initialize my vue instance:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

From App.vue I then dispatch my different components.

Problem is: When I now open a different twig-file I cannot use a different page layout.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me, what the exact problem is. Can you tell why vue.js is not working on `search-result.html.twig`? It might also help to see how vue.js is used in your `index.html.twig`, where it's working, as a reference. Maybe it would also help to compare the content of both template files. The relevant part is whether they extend a template and if it differs and if there are any blocks containing javascript.

Comment: I just edited the initial post. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to have multiple Vue-Apps with different entrypoints that can be used in your Symfony application. From what it looks like you have 3 places where you have to make changes. Depending on details you might have to make additional changes as well.

**Webpack configuration**

This requires that you add these entrypoints to your `webpack.config.js` e.g. by adding an entrypoint for searchApp.

**Your vue "bootstrap" file**

Then you have to copy the `app.js` (or wherever the Vue-snippet from your question is stored) for the new app and make the adjustments, e.g. instead of `import App from './App.vue'` you could have `import SearchApp from './SearchApp.vue'` (and then update the App call further down).

**Your templates**

Now you should have 2 vue apps in your project with 2 webpack entrypoints to load their data (CSS/JS). Your `base.html.twig` will load the javascript for the original app with entrypoint `app`. You now have to tell `search-result.html.twig` to overwrite these files with the ones for the new entrypoint (assuming: `searchApp`):

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block stylesheets %}{{ encore_entry_link_tags('searchApp') }}{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}{{ encore_entry_script_tags('searchApp') }}{% endblock %}
```

In case one of these blocks contains some shared resources you can also add a `{{ parent() }}` call to load them from the base.html.twig, but be careful to not get conflicts in your JS calls. Now the `search-result.html.twig` should load the new Vue-app. You can now change the layout for that app as you see fit and it should not bother your other app.